# How would I grab the first 10 unique items from my database

Tags: c#, linq, unit-of-work

I'm using a UnitOfWork function to get items from my db like this:

```
var items = UnitOfWork.ConversationPosts.Query(postFilter).Take(10);
```

However, is there a way to get the first 10 unique items? I tried using a Linq function like this but I don't know how to use it properly:

```
var items= UnitOfWork.ConversationPosts.Query(postFilter).Take(10).Where(x =>x.id ___);
```

Comment: what column(s) should be unique?

Comment: I just need the id column to be unique. not the whole element. Thanks

Comment: umm.. shouln't the id to be unique by itself? if it's not the primary key then you should use grouping.

Comment: thanks maxlego. The id is actually not the primary key in this instance. Could explain how I can group my items?

Comment: if you use group by, then you cant select the whole row. you get aggregated valeues (min, max, sum ..) and values grouped by. So we need to know what is the result that you want

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = UnitOfWork.ConversationPosts
              .Query(postFilter)
              .GroupBy(c => c.Id)
              .Select(d => d.First())
              .Take(10);
```